# File().walk() not "finding" or ignoring the files inside

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to make an app that grabs all files inside a directory and renames them to add the appropriate extension.

However I can't get this to work, even though it works find on Windows with `kscript` once I try on the phone `File().walk()` seems to only return the directory itself.

```kotlin
val target_directory = "/storage/emulated/0/unknown_files/"

File(target_directory).walk()
    .filterNot { it.isDirectory() }
    .forEach {
        // CAN'T REACH HERE
        var renamed = it.renameTo(File(target_directory + it.name + "." + getMimeType(it)))
        if (renamed) {
            minteger = minteger + 1;
            val displayInteger = findViewById<View>(R.id.integer_number) as TextView
            displayInteger.text = "${minteger}"
        }
    }
```

### Edit:

I'm getting **Permission denied**, obviously

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

is not enough.

Comment: You need to include the Android version. Also, major changes were just made to these permissions, and you need to review the docs to learn about them.

Comment: Note that you need to explicitely [request the permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting).

Comment: Yeah, I just fixed it, need to also ask for permission at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

### Stripped down but this worked for me.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var context: Context? = null
    val PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1
    var activity: Activity? = null
    var permission_array=arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    val target_directory = File("/storage/emulated/0/unknown_files/")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (!target_directory.exists()) {
            target_directory.mkdir()
        }
        context = getApplicationContext()
        activity = this
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        if((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission_array[0]))== PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
            requestPermissions(permission_array, 0)
        }

    }

    private fun requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity!!, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) , PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
    }

}
```